# How to migrate an old Database into a new Database using Microsoft Access

Tags: mysql, ms-access, firebird, firebird1.5

Basically this task is pretty easy when you think about it, but I found no answers in Microsoft **Access** or **MSDN**.  I have to create a connection to a new Database and query the old one. After validating the old data, everything is written in a new fine Form to the my new Database.

Any Ideas?

Add:
Old Database is a **Firebird** Database. This Data needs to be re-structured and migrated to a new **MySQL** Database.

Comment: I see no reason for the ms-access tag.

Comment: cause i have to use MS-Access...well thats what my colleagues say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create the schema separately in MySQL but it's not difficult, there are lots of tutorials, and you can probably find a Firebird tool to export the DDL into a script that will either just work, or be easy to modify.

If you want to use Access in the middle, just attach each of the two external databases from Access (using ODBC or your choice of drivers). You can use the query designer wizards to build a INSERT INTO ... FROM ... type query as you would for any other situation.

Comment: export the DDL : it's why I advice to use Database Workbench. For firebird, I prefer IBExpert but Database Workbench can be used for Firebird and MySQL

Answer (score 2):

If no binary data in your database, I'd suggest just doing a csv export and reimporting.

Comment: but i want to modify the field names etc...can i achieve this with an csv export?

Comment: Yes.  csv import relies only on order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool like [database workbench](http://www.upscene.com/).

Why you want to migrate to MySQL ?

Comment: Database Workbench is a really nice tool. Thank you!
I want to use MySQL cause it is a simple small solution for such a small Access Database.

Comment: In my opinion Firebird is better than MySQL for my needs. I don't know exactly yours but you can take a look here : http://www.itexto.net/devkico/?p=398

Answer (score 0):

if you can access the firebird database via ODBC, i suggest the mysql migration toolkit.